# Why is my CSS code not working in my HTML file?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put my CSS code in the same file as my HTML code, but it does not display properly (I do not want to just link my CSS to my HTML, I already got that to work). I have tried copying and pasting the code, but that does not work. Do I have to do it differently when it is in the same file?

Here is the relevant code:

```
<head>

    <title> Example </title> 

    <style type="text/css">

        input: textarea{
            resize: none;
        }
        input[type=button]{//set the sizes for all of the input buttons
            width: 5em;  
            height: 2em;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <form id = "mainForm" name="mainForm" method="get" action=""  onsubmit=" return checkForm()">


        Type something: <br> <textarea id="info" name="info" > </textarea>


        <input type="button" value="1" id="button1"> </input> 
        <input type="button" value="2" id="button2"> </input> 
        <input type="button" value="3" id="button3"> </input> 

        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset"  class="btn" value="Clear" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is a pic of how it looks when I link it
[image]

And here is a pic of how it looks when I try putting the CSS in the HTLM file
[image]

Comment: Note that CSS only defines [`/* ... */` for comments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments). `// ...` isn't supported by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to specify `input` just `textarea` . you can even use `inline css` for textarea.

```
<style type="text/css">

        textarea{
            resize: none;
        }
        input[type=button]{
        width: 5em; height: 2em;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the pictures I uploaded

Comment: @bobdylan updated now it will work as you expected. removed //set the sizes for all of the input buttons(because //not an css comment)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.  Only problem I see is `input: textarea` is invalid.  Just use `textarea` instead.

```html
<head>
    <title> Example </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        textarea{
            resize: none;
        }
        input[type=button]{ //set the sizes for all of the input buttons
            width: 5em;  
            height: 2em;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
        Type something: <br> <textarea id="info" name="info" > </textarea>
        <input type="button" value="1" id="button1">
        <input type="button" value="2" id="button2">
        <input type="button" value="3" id="button3">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset"  class="btn" value="Clear">
    </form>
</body>
```